# AWS Batch: How do we know which compute environment ordering a batch job is using

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

I am new to AWS .I have two compute environments. When I submit my batch JOB how do I know which compute environment is it using? I don't see anything on Batch job logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you attach two or more environments to a given queue, then Batch will attempt to use resources from the environments in the order they are listed. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_queue_parameters.html):

> The order of the compute environment. Compute environments are tried
>   in ascending order. For example, if two compute environments are
>   associated with a job queue, the compute environment with a lower
>   order integer value is tried for job placement first.

In most circumstances, you will only have a single compute environment for a given queue, in which case the env is determined by the queue.